# " npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM " error on vercel while deployment

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vite, vercel

```
Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1 (Hive)
Cloning github.com/tj8016/Delicious-Zone (Branch: main, Commit: b7c0a4c)
Skipping build cache, deployment was triggered without cache.
Cloning completed: 562.879ms
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 32.5.3
Running "install" command: `npm install`...
`npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for @esbuild/darwin-arm64@0.19.5: wanted {"os":"darwin","cpu":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","cpu":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid os:   darwin
npm ERR! notsup Actual os:  linux
npm ERR! notsup Valid cpu:  arm64
npm ERR! notsup Actual cpu: x64
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-11-09T05_41_08_351Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1`
```

When I build my `react+vite` for production on vercel and this error comes but in my local system the code works fine.
Please help me out from this error.
Thanks in advance.

I want to deploy my react+vite app on vercel but this error coming but in local system the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me!
https://blog.hao.dev/fixing-esbuild-related-cpu-architecture-error-on-apple-silicon-macs

It turns out my local node (x64) version was inconsistent with my local machine (arm64). I reset by uninstalling node, reinstalling node, rebooting VS code and my terminals.

With everything reset, I removed all specific versions of esbuild from my package.json (I had @esbuild/darwin-arm64) and installed the generic `esbuild`. The generic `esbuild` being installed will leave it to whatever machine is deploying the code to pull its correct esbuild version.